# Neteller TransferOut with PHP / CURL

Tags: php, curl, payment

I'm having some problems using the Neteller API to transfer money out of our merchant account to a user. I've succcessfully received the accessToken, however when I try using transferOut I just get invalid credentials? The code I'm using is:

```
    $headers = array(
        "Content-type" => "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $accessToken
    );

    //build the request body structure
    $requestParams = array(
        "payeeProfile" => array(
            "email" => $the_email_address_to_send_to
        ),
        "transaction" => array(
            "merchantRefId" => $transaction_id,
            "amount" => $amount,
            "currency" => $currencyCode
        )
    );

    // encode the requestParams to a string
    $requestParams = json_encode($requestParams);

    // The curl stuff
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.neteller.com/v1/transferOut");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestParams);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Ok lets send this lovely looking curl over
    $serverOutput = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
```

Obviously all variables ($transaction_id, $amount, $currency) are set appropriately. However the response I get back is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => 5279
        [message] => Authentication credentials are invalid
    )

)
```

I'm confused, surely the accessToken is the credentials I need, and theyve already been received. Am I meant to include anything else in the transferOut curl postfields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$headers` does not look OK - try `$headers = array("Content-type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken);`. At least this is the format according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Yep that was it - simple as. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [user3584460's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010775/neteller-transferout-with-php-curl#comment52081278_32010775):

> `$headers` does not look OK - try `$headers = array("Content-type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken);`. At least this is the format according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Note, the Merchant Ref ID also needs to be a certain length. unsure what - can't find reference, but 8 characters is not long enough.